# Checking database and avoid duplicate before inserting data by using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to check database before inserting data to avoid duplicate. I store the URLs in array, and inserting those URL in "link" column on a table. So first I am checking the column, istere same URL or not? If not, then insert the data with this code.

Here is my whole codes of database inserting;

```
foreach ($outlineUrls  as $outlineUrl) {
    $html = file_get_contents($outlineUrl);
    $DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
    $DOMParser->loadHTML($html);


    $changeForMyDB = [
                            'remote_id' => '',
                            'region' => '関西',
                            'link' => json_encode($outlineUrl),
                            'name' => '',
                            'price' => '',
                            'extend' => '',
                            'address' => '',
                            'hows_old' => '',
                            'rooms' => '',
                            'old' => '',
                            'entery' => '',
                            'balcon_m2' => '',
                            'company_name' => '',
                            'script_from' => ''
                        ];

            $allPTags = $DOMParser->getElementsByTagName('p');
            foreach($allPTags as $ptag){
                if($ptag->getAttribute('class') == 'c-name'){
                        $changeForMyDB['name'] = trim($ptag->nodeValue);
                }
            }

            $changeForMyDB['address'] = trim($DOMParser->getElementsByTagName('dd')[0]->nodeValue);

            $allTables = $DOMParser->getElementsByTagName('table');
            foreach($allTables as $table){
                foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
                    $property = trim($tr->getElementsByTagName('th')[0]->nodeValue);
                    $value = trim($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')[0]->nodeValue);

                    switch ($property) {
                        case '物件名':
                            $changeForMyDB['name'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '販売価格':
                            $changeForMyDB['price'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '専有面積':
                            $changeForMyDB['extend'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '所在地':
                            $changeForMyDB['address'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '総戸数':
                            $changeForMyDB['hows_old'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '間取り':
                            $changeForMyDB['rooms'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '竣工時期':
                            $changeForMyDB['old'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '管理会社':
                            $changeForMyDB['company_name'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '入居時期':
                            $changeForMyDB['entery'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '入居時期':
                            $changeForMyDB['entery'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case 'バルコニー面積':
                            $changeForMyDB['balcon_m2'] = $value;
                            break;
                        default:
                            # code...
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

if(Estates::where('link','=',$outlineUrl)->count() > 0)
{

   $this->error('There is link.');

} else {

        Estates::insertGetId($changeForMyDB);

        $this->line('Data saved.');

       }
```

But the problem is here. It's inserting the data without checking it!
Any idea what's the problem is? Thank you, for your help.

Comment: Please read about Laravel's Validation, you don't have to reinvent the wheel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

Comment: You did not show the code where you insert the URL into your table.

Comment: @Namoshek I update the question with whole codes, you can check it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the updateOrCreate() method to achieve the goal of only inserting if the record does not exist:

```
$estate = Estates::updateOrCreate(['link' =>  $outlineUrl], $changeForMyDB);
```

This will check if there is an `Estate::where('link', '=', $outlineUrl)`. If none is found, it will create a new `Estate´ and add all data from`$changeForMyDB`to it. If one exists, it will fetch it from the database, add all data from`$changeForMyDB`. Then it will persist the changes. Read more about that here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods

---

To avoid issues with concurrent requests, you should also wrap your update within a database transaction. This ensures that the database has the same state when you checked for uniqueness as when you store your data.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $estate = Estates::updateOrCreate(['link' =>  $outlineUrl], $changeForMyDB);
});
```

If you don't want to update existing entries, use something like this:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    if (Estates::where('link','=',$outlineUrl)->count() === 0) {
        $estate = Estates::create($changeForMyDB);
    }
});
```

Beware that `Estates::create($data)` and `Estates::insert($data)` are not the same. The `create($data)` function will create a model, fill it with the `$data` and return the persisted model. It will also fire all Eloquent events that are relevant for the create method. The `insert($data)` method on the other hand will not create an Eloquent model and will therefore also not fire any Eloquent events. It will directly insert the data into the database. This is more lightweight and faster, but you should keep that in mind.

---

If you want to check if the record already existed and report some kind of error, you can check with this:

```
if (!$estate->wasRecentlyCreated()) {
    // report error here
}
```

Comment: I update the question with my whole codes mate, can you check it?

Comment: okay, thanks for the long answer and sorry for burden. I understand the issue thanks to your answer. I want to insert data, if there is no data. But also if there is data, I want to update that and keep the old data. because I need to use one of the old data's column. I think I need a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

public function rules() {

```
    return [
                    
        'tool_id' => ['required','integer','unique:assign_toolto_joborders'],
        'joborder_id' => ['required','integer'],
        'assign_date' => ['required','date_format:d-m-Y'],
        'tool_qty' => ['required','integer']
        
    ];
}
```

User these rules

$request->validate($this->rules());